# Recursion with more than one function

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

some of you may find this question a little odd, but i really want to know if this program is recursive or not, and that is all I want to know.

```
(defun howmany(sez)
  (if (null sez)
      0
    (+ 1 (howmany (cdr sez)))))

(defun sum(sez)
  (if (null sez)
      0
    (+ (car sez) (sum(cdr sez)))))

(defun avg(sez)
  (if (null sez)
      0
    (/ (sum sez) (howmany sez))))

(print (avg '(100 200 300)))
```

Thank for all your answers!

Comment: It's next to impossible to read unformatted Lisp code.  Please indent your code.  E.g, your code should probably look like: http://pastebin.com/raw/ZdPp8A0i .  Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39005847/edit) link under the question.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking though.  SUM calls itself, and HOWMANY calls itself, so those are both recursive, certainly.  Note that you could just do `(defun avg (seq) (/ (reduce '+ seq) (length seq))`.  There's no need to reimplement LENGTH and a list summation function.

Comment: The thing is im not allowed to use in-built functions all has to be implemented, but yeah my thoughts are that this is recursive and i just wanted someone more exptert to make a thought about it.

Comment: But you **are** using built-in functions: +, /, null, car, cdr (and that's on top of some built-in non-functions: defun and if).

Comment: yeah, that is true, we have gone a little offtopic here as all I want to know if this is recursive or not, i know i can improve program and make it 2 line short but thats not the case here

Comment: Every function that eventually calls the name of the function it implements is recursive. All of your functions do that. They are even recursive processes since they grow the stack while you could easily made all of this iterative processes by using an accumulator. You'll probably learn more about that soon :-) Is `sez` list in some language?

Comment: That kind of answer I was looking for, thank you very much! :)

Comment: If you couldn't figure this out yourself, you must not understand what "recursive" means.

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look at your code and format it a little bit more, in order to be easily read by a lisper

```
(defun howmany (sez)
  (if (null sez)
      0
      (+ 1 (howmany (cdr sez)))))

(defun sum (sez)
  (if (null sez)
      0
      (+ (car sez) (sum (cdr sez)))))

(defun avg (sez)
  (if (null sez)
      0
      (/ (sum sez) (howmany sez))))

(print (avg '(100 200 300)))
```

Then analize this script, it contains three functions an a last s-expression which evaluate the functions.

For this three functions, avg, sum and howmany,

There is a story titled Martin and the Dragon, you can find in chapter 8 from here [Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/) and you should read, which sumarizes in:

> The dragon, beneath its feigned distaste for Martin's questions,
>   actually enjoyed teaching him about recursion. One day it decided to
>   formally explain what recursion means. The dragon told Martin to
>   approach every recursive problem as if it were a journey. If he
>   followed three rules for solving problems recursively, he would always
>   complete the journey successfully.
>
> The dragon explained the rules this way:
>
> 1. Know when to stop.
> 2. Decide how to take one step.
> 3. Break the journey down into that step plus a smaller journey.

Let's see the functions howmany and sum

1. Know when to stop
   it stops when sez is null, i.e. when the list is nil
2. Decide how to take one step

the if have two ways or 0 for both or

```
(+ 1 (howmany (cdr sez)))
(+ (car sez) (sum (cdr sez)))
```

3. Break the joourney down into that step plus a smaller journey

in the last expressions, the list is smaller take out the first and then continue, with the smaller list

So, this two functions are recursive, the other avg, is not recursive, only take cares of the empty list, in order to prevent dividing by zero or zero/zero indetermination.

Hope this helps